# Android Studio Emulator apk install error

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, apk

I've started the android emulator (android 5.1), wanted to install an apk through drag and drop, but I get this error message:

```
pm install-create -r -t --user current --full -S 203239352' returns error 'Unknown failure: Error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "current"'
```

I've tried on an m1 mac and a windows pc. On the mac I tried arm and arm64, on windows tried it with x86. Got apk files with matching architectures for all of them with chrome version (95.0.4638.x) compatible with android 5.1. I get the same error message for all of them.

Comment: Just use `adb install myapp.apk` on the PC side. The used emulator image is too old for the drag & drop operation. You should really use a newer Android image, at least Android 9 or 10.

Comment: seeing the usage rates, I would like to go as low as possible. because of another issue, I'll go for 7.1.1, there the drag and drop still doesn't work (has a different issue, it doesn't recognize some arguments), but I will try your solution, thx! I'm not yet familiar with the command, I'm building an app with a cross platform runtime.

Comment: On Android the most recent versions make more problems than the old versions. therefore I would recommend to first test your app on a recent Android version and then on an older.